# ggplot why are bars not stacked?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a stacked bar graph however my output shows overlaid bars instead of stacked. How can I rectify this?

```
#Create data
date <- as.Date(rep(c("1/1/2016", "2/1/2016", "3/1/2016", "4/1/2016", "5/1/2016"),2))
sales <- c(23,52,73,82,12,67,34,23,45,43)*1000
geo <- c(rep("Western Territory",5), rep("Eastern Territory",5))
data <- data.frame(date, sales, geo)

#Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=date, y=sales, fill=geo))+
    stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="bar") +
    ggtitle("TITLE")
```

Plot output:
[image: GGPLOT stacked bar graph]

As you can see from the summarized table below, it confirms the bars are not stacked:

```
>#Verify plot is correct
>ddply(data, c("date"), summarize, total=sum(sales))
    date  total
1 0001-01-20  90000
2 0002-01-20  86000
3 0003-01-20  96000
4 0004-01-20 127000
5 0005-01-20  55000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include `position="stack"` in your `statSummary`:

```
stat_summary(position="stack",fun.y=sum, geom="bar")
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, since your data are already summarized, you could use `geom_col` (the short hand for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`):

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=date, y=sales, fill=geo))+
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%d")
```

Produces:

[image]

Note that I changed the date formatting (by adding `format = "%m/%d/%Y"` to the `as.Date` call) and explictly set the axis lable formatting.

If your actual data have more than one entry per period, you can always `summarise` first, then pass that into `ggplot` instead of the raw data.